# Recieve Angular Firebase Document and Return it

Tags: angular, database, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a Document from my FireDatabase, the Model is a user, like this:

```
export class User {
    useremail: string;
    userid: string;
    username: string;

    constructor(usermail: string, userid: string, username: string ){
        this.useremail = usermail;
        this.userid = userid;
        this.username = username;
    }
  }
```

This is the Service:

```
  getUser(uid){
    this.firestore.collection('/users').doc<User>(uid).snapshotChanges().subscribe(res => {
      this.userData = new User(res.payload.data().useremail,
                               res.payload.data().userid,
                               res.payload.data().username);    
                               console.log(this.userData) 
                              retrun this.userData;
    })
  }
```

so when i call this Service in my component where i need the Data it looks like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userData = this.userService.getUser(this.authService.getUserId());
  console.log(this.userData)
  }
```

But the userData log is undefiened. i supose i need to wait for the function to finish but i dont know how i can do it. 
Can somebody Help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to Close this issue:

the esiest way is to return an observable like this.

```
constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) { }
```

```
getById(string: id) {
return this.afs.doc<any>(id).valueChnages();
}
```

```
this.service.getById('12').subscribe{doc => console.log(doc.name);}
```